# The Meaning of -1.#IND

Tags: c++, visual-c++, double

I have been running into a problem where some of my doubles have been assigned the value -1.#IND, and I have absolutely no idea what it means or how exactly to catch it.

Any help on the issue would be much appreciated.

Kind Regards,
Alex

Comment: I believe my question is a duplicate, sorry about that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-1.#IND    It is Negative indefinite NaN.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/02/21/10395734.aspx

Comment: No, it's not negative infinity. It's an "indefinite" value, which is a special type of NaN (whereas an infinity is not a NaN). Read the article.

Comment: Yes, my mistake. I have changed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
-1.#IND
```

according to [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/02/21/10395734.aspx) article

> is the Indefinite NaN, which is a special type of quiet NaN generated
>   under specific conditions. If you perform an invalid arithmetic
>   operation like add positive infinity and negative infinity, or take
>   the square root of a negative number, then the IEEE standard requires
>   that the result be a quiet NaN, but it doesn't appear to specify what
>   quiet NaN exactly. Different floating point processor manufacturers
>   chose different paths. The term Indefinite NaN refers to this special
>   quiet NaN, whatever the processor ends up choosing it to be.